# WPF Panel.ZIndex for child elements

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I'm developing a small visual designer and I need to implement a function of indexing elements. All elements have their own level of visibility depend on each other. I'm not using ZIndex for main elements so they are displayed as they are in visual tree. But all elements when they are in set index mode have a region with an index number. The problem is that these regions inherit zindex of their parents. I tried to set up for these regions zindex = 1000, but it didn't help.

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="IndexRegion" TargetType="ContentControl">
        <Border>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <!--<TextBlock Text="Индекс: "></TextBlock>-->
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding TabIndex}"></TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
        </Border>
    </ControlTemplate>
<Style x:Key="IndexRegionStyle" TargetType="ContentControl">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="1 -15 0 0"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="{Binding IsTabIndexVisible, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource VisibilityOfBool}}"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="Panel.ZIndex" Value="1000"></Setter>
    </Style>


<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModel:WizardFormTextFieldViewModel}">
  <wfSurface:DesignSurfaceItemContainer Width="{Binding Width}" Height="{Binding Height}" ClipToBounds="False">
    <Grid VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">

      <ContentControl Style="{StaticResource IndexRegionStyle}" Template="{StaticResource IndexRegion}">
      </ContentControl> --- this is an index region

      <Border Style="{StaticResource WrongElement}">
        <Border Style="{StaticResource TextFieldStyle}">                        
        </Border>
      </Border>
    </Grid>
  </wfSurface:DesignSurfaceItemContainer>           
</DataTemplate>
```

How can I make all regions to be above all main elements?

Thank you!

Comment: Please organize the code. You can do that by pressing 4 spaces at the start of the line

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ZIndex is an index to organize the z-order of siblings (child controls of the same container)

If you want elements to be on top of 'everything' you need to add a new container that is on top of everything. You cannot specify this from a lower level such as this Template. The UI remains a hierarchy, you can't break that as far as I know.

Comment: it is very disappointing, I thought about that, but I tried to keep the hope, because this makes the solution much heavier (

Comment: The solution will be different but not much heavier. Just add a top grid/canvas and add children to it that are bound by the items lower in the object hierarchy. This is simply the result of the visual tree structure not being the same as the object structure.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunatly it doesn't help me, because I have a container element that can contain other elements, so an hierarchy can be very deep and some elements can be invisible, because they are not placed on a visible bound of a container element, so it makes me to realize whether element is visible or not. I think I will use adorner ability for each container element to resolve this issue. Each container element will draw tab index for its elements on its adorner layer.

Comment: When you make an object hierarchy you can bind the elements of the visual tree to ANY object/property in the hierarchy. You could add a visibility property to an object and bind to that property on several levels in the visual tree.

Comment: yes, but I believe it would be more difficult than using an adorner feature, because if we use an adorner feature we don't have to know whether an element visible or not . The second reason is that we would have to make transform x,y coordinates of each element that isn't on the global level, because they have x,y depended on their container element top-left corner. We don't have to make this calculation with adorner either.